# SQL query with WHERE clause from a cell value

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access-2010, vba

I'm trying to write my SQl in VBA Excel 2010 to get the data from Access 2010, everything works fine except when the `WHERE` clause value is a string value from a cell.

I tried so many different solutions but nothing worked, here is my Sql and the value to be changed is "A1.Value"

```
sQRY = "SELECT * FROM Master Where Master.name = A1.Value"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're building a query string, you need to include *the value* of the cell, not its address:

```
sQRY = "SELECT * FROM Master WHERE Master.name = '" & Range("A1").Value & "'"
```

Notice that, if the value of A1 is a string, you need to enclose it in quotes or double quotes.

Hope this helps

Comment: @HansUp Indeed! (duh! forgot to put it, just corrected)

Comment: thank yu for yuor reply, yes the value is a string, how do i add the double quotes? adding them instead of the single qute gives an error, and adding them after the & sign prints "Range("A1").Value

Comment: Single quotes are enough, but if you want double quotes, concatenate with `Chr(34)`